# how to verify that a specific cell in a table contains a certain value in a link with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a table similar to the following

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>some text</td>
        <td>other text</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/process/100/">process data</a> or
            <a href="/delete/100/">delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some text</td>
        <td>other text</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/process/101/">process data</a> or
            <a href="/delete/101/">delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some text</td>
        <td>other text</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/process/102/">process data</a> or
            <a href="/delete/102/">delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like to check with Python and Selenium that the cell in row 1, column 3 contains a link to `/process/100/`

I am able to access the text with

```
cell_content = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').text
```

but I would like to access

```
href="/process/101/"
```

to check if it contains `101`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_attribute()` method as below

```
cell_href = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]').get_attribute('href')
assert "101" in cell_href
```